# Copy components of array to another array and conditionally change value

Tags: arrays, c

I have three char-arrays, filled with char or integers. I want to copy the components of each field in another "empty_array" with the condition:

- each arabic number should be copied 1:1
- each component which is not an arabic number I want to translate to the char '0'
- as I want to print it with the %s operator '\0' should also be copied, to terminate the char-array to end the

So for example, for

```
char array1[6] = {'H', '4', '1', '1', 'o', '\0'};
```

it should print: 04110.

Therefore I have defined this function:

```
void copy_only_digits(char v[], char w[], int size)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                if ((v[i] >= '0' && v[i] <= '9') || v[i] == '\0') {
                        w[i] = v[i];
                } else {
                        w[i] = '0';
                }
        }
}
```

and I print it in the main-function with

```
        copy_only_digits(array1, empty_array1, sizeof(array1));
        printf("%s\n", empty_array1);
```

The output is as expected. But I am not able to print it for each of the three arrays (one line for each array) with only one "empty_array".
I have tried it with a "clearance" of the "empty_array" with the following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(empty_array); i++) {
        empty_array[i] = '\0';
```

But it is just not working. So I am now using three arrays which is not what I am looking for.

The whole code now looks as follow:

```
void copy_only_digits(char v[], char w[], int size);

int main(void)
{
        int size;
        size = 30;
        char array1[6] = {'H', '4', '1', '1', 'o', '\0'};
        char array2[6] = {44, 49, 65, 86, 121, '\0'};
        char array3[12] = {'I', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'a', 't', 'i', 'k', '1', '\0'};
        char empty_array1[size];
        char empty_array2[size];
        char empty_array3[size];

        copy_only_digits(array1, empty_array1, sizeof(array1));
        printf("%s\n", empty_array1);

        copy_only_digits(array2, empty_array2, sizeof(array2));
        printf("%s\n", empty_array2);

        copy_only_digits(array3, empty_array3, sizeof(array3));
        printf("%s\n", empty_array3);
        return 0;
}

void copy_only_digits(char v[], char w[], int size)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                if ((v[i] >= '0' && v[i] <= '9') || v[i] == '\0') {
                        w[i] = v[i];
                } else {
                        w[i] = '0';
                }
        }
}
```

In short: I want to avoid `empty_array1[size]` etc. but just have one `empty_array[size]` and use it all over again.

Thanks!

Edit:
The failing code (still don't know why it is not working):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy_only_digits(char v[], char w[], int size);

int main(void)
{
        int i, size;
        size = 30;
        char array1[6] = {'H', '4', '1', '1', 'o', '\0'};
        char array2[6] = {44, 49, 65, 86, 121, '\0'};
        char array3[12] = {'I', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'a', 't', 'i', 'k', '1', '\0'};
        char empty_array[15];
        
        
        copy_only_digits(array1, empty_array, size);
        printf("%s\n", empty_array);

        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                empty_array[i] = '\0';
        }

        copy_only_digits(array2, empty_array, size);
        printf("%s\n", empty_array);

        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                empty_array[i] = '\0';
        }

        copy_only_digits(array3, empty_array, size);
        printf("%s\n", empty_array);

        return 0;
}

void copy_only_digits(char v[], char w[], int size)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                if ((v[i] >= '0' && v[i] <= '9') || v[i] == '\0') {
                        w[i] = v[i];
                } else {
                        w[i] = '0';
                }
        }
}
```

The working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy_only_digits(char v[], char w[], int size);

int main(void)
{
        int i, size;
        size = 30;
        char array1[6] = {'H', '4', '1', '1', 'o', '\0'};
        char array2[6] = {44, 49, 65, 86, 121, '\0'};
        char array3[12] = {'I', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'a', 't', 'i', 'k', '1', '\0'};
        char empty_array[size];


        copy_only_digits(array1, empty_array, sizeof(array1));
        printf("%s\n", empty_array);

        copy_only_digits(array2, empty_array, sizeof(array2));
        printf("%s\n", empty_array);

        copy_only_digits(array3, empty_array, sizeof(array3));
        printf("%s\n", empty_array);
        return 0;
}

void copy_only_digits(char v[], char w[], int size)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                if ((v[i] >= '0' && v[i] <= '9') || v[i] == '\0') {
                        w[i] = v[i];
                } else {
                        w[i] = '0';
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me as is; just changing the 3 arrays for a single one (see https://ideone.com/59ESFn). Are you perhaps passing the arrays around and therefore transforming them to pointers? `sizeof array` **is very diffrent then** `sizeof pointer`. Functions receive pointers, not arrays (even when defined with `foo(char x[])` ==> `x` is a pointer). Try `strlen(array) + 1` instead of `sizeof array`.

Comment: _" it is just not working"_ - How is it not working? The program you've posted seems to do what you described that you want to do.

Comment: _whole code_ needs to include `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Post the failing version of code.

Comment: added failing and working code now in the initial post. 
Still don't understand why the for-loop in main-function stops the code from working.

Comment: You're using `size` in several wrong places in the failing code: to set `30` elements of an array with `6` bytes available, to copy `30` elements from an array with `6` bytes to an array with `15` bytes, ...